# Morphism of schemes determined by their induced maps of $Z$ valued points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, schemes, morphism

I am doing an exercise that states: morphism of schemes $X \rightarrow Y$  is determined by their induced maps of $Z$ valued points, as $Z$ varies over all schemes. I am a bit confused with this question (My attempted solution seems way too simple...) I would appreciate any assistance! Thank you!

Comment: That is essentially the Yoneda lemma. It really is very simple.

Comment: @ZhenLin Is it actually as simple as if I have two morphisms $\phi_1, \phi_2 : X \rightarrow Y$ and if the induced maps of $Z$ points agree at all schemes $Z$, then in particular they agree at $Z= X$; therefore $\phi_1 = \phi_2$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

For any morphism of schemes $\alpha: X \to Y$, and for any scheme $Z$, denote the induced map of $Z$-valued points $$\alpha^Z_*: X(Z) \to Y(Z)$$ which is defined as $\alpha^Z_*(\varphi)=\alpha \circ \varphi$.

---

Let $\pi, \rho: X \to Y$ be two morphisms of schemes, and suppose for all schemes $Z$, we have $\pi^Z_*=\rho^Z_*: X(Z) \to Y(Z)$. Then, in particular, letting $Z=X$, we have $\pi^X_*: X(X) \to Y(X)$, $\rho^X_*: X(X) \to Y(X)$ satisfying
$$\pi=\pi^X_*(\mathrm{Id}_X)=\rho^X_*(\mathrm{Id}_X)=\rho.$$